# unable to add new text box on onclick() using javascript and disable an element

Tags: javascript, html

I am not able to add a new input box after the onclick event is called and is there way to disable the select options after the input box appears? I am sorry for such a noob question but I am at the dead end here, been trying this for an hour. Please link me to a place where I can easily learn JS with examples.

```
   <script>
    function funcGet(val)
    {
      if(val=="Create new category")
      {
         var element = document.createElement("input");
         element.setAttribute("type", "input");
         element.setAttribute("name", "new_cat");
         var foo = document.getElementById("cat");
         foo.appendChild(element);
       }
    }
    </script>
    <div name="cat">
    <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a topic name" name="word"><br/>
    <select name = "category" onchange="funcGet(this.value);">
    <?php
       displayCat();
    ?>
    </select>
    </div>
    <select name = "site_type">
    <?php
       displaySitetype();
    ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit data">
    </form>
```

Comment: Your calling `document.getElementById("cat")` without that element actually having an ID, add `id="cat"` to your `div` and your element will be appended correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `<div name="cat">` to

```
<div id="cat">
```

.getElementById only works on IDs,

as in

```
document.getElementById("cat");
```

If you want to leave `<div name="cat">` you should use `.getElementsByTagName[0]` instead.

As foir a a link to learn JavaScript by example, I recommend the [W3Schools JavaScript Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp), as they let you try out code as you learn it on their website. Once you become more familiar, you can reference the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

Here

`var foo = document.getElementById("cat");` is giving  null

There is no element exist with id `cat`

Error is:TypeError: `foo is null`

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<div name="cat">
```

To this:

```
<div id="cat">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>
    Untitled Document
  </title>
  <script>

    function generateRow() {
      var d=document.getElementById("div");
      d.innerHTML+="<td><input type='text'<td><input type='text'<td><input type='text' name='food'name='food'name='food'name='food'>";
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <label>

        <input name="food" type="text" id="food" />
      </label>
      <td>
        <input name="food" type="text" id="food" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="food" type="text" id="food" />
      </td>
      <div id="div">
      </div>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="generateRow()"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
        </label>
      </td>
    </form>
  </body>
```